# Determine if a memory location changes value

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

In Windows (both 32 and 64 bit), through program (C++) is it possible to determine if a certain memory location has changed? I am trying to extrapolate the concept that we see in Visual Studio where we can set data break point.

**Use Case**: `I understand its a dirty hack, but the fastest to implement to be re-implemented later`

I am sharing data across process boundary (read between a 32 bit client and 64 bit server). The Client allocates memory (beyond our control) and passes the address to the server. The Server allocates a storage to shadow the client memory and via various code path can update that shadowed memory location. Instead of identifying and trapping each of these location (I was trying to find an easier path), to raise an event on change and eventually write back the data through `WriteProcessMemory` to the client process

Comment: Your purported "use case" merely restates the question. You never explain why you want to do this. Normally, whoever changes the data would, say, signal an event, and whoever wants to be notified would wait on said event.

Comment: The concept of code wildly scribbling bytes into memory is why debuggers have data breakpoints.  It has no place in a sane program, you instead find the code that does these writes and alter its side-effects.

Comment: Setting the page protection to readonly and installing an exception handler will do that, but... see comment by Igor Tandetnik.

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking at threads and mutexes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Updated the Use Case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst it's probably possible to find a solution using a combination of `VirtualProtect` and the [Windows debug interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I'm not sure it's a particularly good solution for this scenario. One of the problems is that you introduce a delay on every new write, and you are looking at a transfer to another process that is monitoring the program as a "debugger". That process will then have to "unprotect" that page, mark it as "updated" for the other Server (or Client, depending on which direction you are going), and "continue" the application making the update. This is quite time consuming. And of course, there is no trivial way to know when the writing process has completed a sequence of updates. You also need to know exactly where to "continue" when there is a SEH "__except" call, and it's not always entirely trivial do to that, especially if the code is in the middle of a memcpy or something like that.

When I worked with graphics, I know that both our and some competitors driver would do this, first write-protect the memory, and then by hooking into the windows own page-fault handler, look up the page-fault, see if it's the special region(s), and if so, mark that page as updated and reset it to writeable. This allowed the driver to only copy the updated regions. But in this case, there is a distinct "I want to draw this stuff" after all the updates have been made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I at least understand and convince the pain I would have to incur to accomplish my goal through the desired approach. Both your and Jerry's answer states how I can achieve it, but your answer goes beyond and throws light on the pitfall. There for I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to badly enough, you can use the debug API to set a breakpoint on your own data, which will be triggered on a write, just like the VS API does.

The basics of this are to start a thread to do the "debugging".  It will:

1. temporarily stop the primary thread.
2. Get that thread's registers with GetThreadContext
3. set the address to break on in one of DR0 through DR 3.
4. Set the size of the data in question in DR 6.
5. Set the type of breakpoint (data write, in this case) in DR 7.
6. Use SetThreadContext to tell the primary thread to use the modified registers.
7. Restart execution of the primary thread.

That's going from memory, so although I believe it's pretty close to the basic idea, I may have gotten a detail or two wrong, or (more likely) left out a few steps.

In most cases, it's going to be easier to do something at the source level, where you overload `operator=` for the target in question, so you get some code executed during assignment to the data. Then in that operator you can (for example) set an Event that code in another thread waits on (and reacts appropriately).

Another possibility (especially if you want to break on any access to a whole range of addresses) is to use `VirtualProtect` to force an exception on any access to that block of memory. Like a debug exception, this will be triggered synchronously, so if you want asynchronous execution you'll have to accomplish it by setting an Event (or whatever) and having another thread waiting on that so it'll execute when the Event is set.

Comment: Is there a way to set breakpoints in Windows for this (I don't mean "is there", but rather is there a published API call to set a breakpoint for a specific address(range))?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes and no. `GetThreadContext`/`SetThreadContext` with the `CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS` flag will retrieve/set the debug registers, which you can use to set breakpoints. The content of a `CONTEXT` is only documented in WinNT.h though, and most documentation on how to really use the debug registers will be from Intel or AMD, not Microsoft.

Comment: I have updated the Use Case. I understand that there are cleaner ways to do this, but something I need to implement in couple of hours so need a hack to achieve it.

Comment: +1 @Abhijit You're going to be hard-pressed to get a better answer than this, a veritable step-by-step list of what to do, especially given the context of your question.

Comment: Only problem with the debug register solution is that it's very limited in the number of locations to "watch". Only 4 at any given time, and only 4/8 bytes per item (8 bytes only available in 64-bit mode). So it's not particularly useful unless you have a very restricted area to monitor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the detail steps mentioned. I am accepting @MatsPetersson 's answer as it also encompass the problems that I was supposed to know.